# При нажатии на area должна выводится картинка, но она выводится только на секунду

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<img src="dom888.jpg" usemap="#genlinks" class="mapq" alt="" />

<map name="genlinks" id="genlinks">
        <area onclick="showImg()" onmouseover="over($(this).index()+1)" shape="poly" alt="" title=""  coords="128,630,173,603,407,607,408,645,170,644,128,657,128,656" class="link"  href="" target="" />
        <area onclick="showImg()" onmouseover="over($(this).index()+1)" shape="poly" alt="" title="" coords="130,601,175,569,407,577,408,616,172,610,127,633,128,625" href="" target="" />
        <area onclick="showImg()" onmouseover="over($(this).index()+1)" shape="poly" title="" coords="131,575,176,533,406,547,407,583,174,573,129,604,129,604" href="" target="" />
        <area onmouseover="over($(this).index()+1)" shape="poly" alt="" title=""  coords="485,148,579,149,579,201,485,201,485,177,472,177,472,201,457,200,457,152,474,151,473,168,485,168"  href="" target="" />
</map>

<div id="Step2">

    <img src="2-9-new888.jpg" usemap="#genlinks" class="mapq" alt="" />
    <map name="genlinks" id="genlinks">
        <area onmouseover="over($(this).index()+1)" shape="poly" alt="" title=""  coords="485,148,579,149,579,201,485,201,485,177,472,177,472,201,457,200,457,152,474,151,473,168,485,168"  href="" target="" />
        <area onmouseover="over($(this).index()+1)" shape="poly" alt="" title="" coords="130,601,175,569,407,577,408,616,172,610,127,633,128,625" href="" target="" />
        <area onmouseover="over($(this).index()+1)" shape="poly" title="" coords="131,575,176,533,406,547,407,583,174,573,129,604,129,604" href="" target="" />
    </map>
</div>



document.getElementById('Step2' ).style.display = 'none';
var visible = true;

function showImg() {
    if (visible) {
    document.getElementById('Step2' ).style.display = 'block';

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Дело в том, что при кликах на `<area>` страница пытается обновиться и перезагружает ваш JavaScript. Чтобы этого избежать, используйте

```
href="javascript: void(0)"
```

или по старенькому, топорному

```
href="#"
```

Такого вида заглушки помогут в решении вашей проблемы!

Answer (score 0):

В своем JavaScript вы пытаетесь отобразить элемент с id = "Step2", но не указали часть этого кода в вопросе. поэтому ответить на Ваш вопрос затруднительно, могу ограничиться советом: юзайте visibility: hidden; вместо display:none. Помогает избежать множество проблем.
А вообще, у Вас очень странный JavaScript код. Для чего вы делаете проверку на заведомо указанную переменную "visibile"?